# Error with Sequelize Serverless Offline Migrations

Tags: amazon-web-services, sequelize.js, nodes, database-migration, serverless

With this command `sls offline start --httpPort 12012 -s local` server is started successfully on local env.

But this command result is error `sls offline migrations --httpPort 12012 -s local`

```
  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
 
  "migrations" is not a valid sub command. Run "serverless offline" to see a more helpful error message for this command.
 
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
 
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          linux
     Node Version:              14.4.0
     Framework Version:         1.75.1
     Plugin Version:            3.6.16
     SDK Version:               2.3.1
     Components Version:        2.32.0
```

If I run `serverless migrations up` an error occurs.

```
Serverless: Setting up connections...
Serverless: Looking for pending migrations...
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SequelizeMeta` (`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE , PRIMARY KEY (`name`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `SequelizeMeta`
Executing (default): SELECT `name` FROM `SequelizeMeta` AS `SequelizeMeta` ORDER BY `SequelizeMeta`.`name` ASC;
Serverless: Applying pending migrations...
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SequelizeMeta` (`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE , PRIMARY KEY (`name`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `SequelizeMeta`
Executing (default): SELECT `name` FROM `SequelizeMeta` AS `SequelizeMeta` ORDER BY `SequelizeMeta`.`name` ASC;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SequelizeMeta` (`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE , PRIMARY KEY (`name`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `SequelizeMeta`
Executing (default): SELECT `name` FROM `SequelizeMeta` AS `SequelizeMeta` ORDER BY `SequelizeMeta`.`name` ASC;
Serverless: Error while applying migrations
Serverless: Looking for migration that has problems...
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SequelizeMeta` (`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE , PRIMARY KEY (`name`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `SequelizeMeta`
Executing (default): SELECT `name` FROM `SequelizeMeta` AS `SequelizeMeta` ORDER BY `SequelizeMeta`.`name` ASC;
Serverless: Something wrong with 20200728165728-init.js
```

Currently, DB is updated by using sequelize sync which sometimes locks tables.

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import mysql2 from 'mysql2';

const db = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DB_NAME,
  process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  {
    omitNull: true,
    dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
    dialectModule: mysql2,
    dialectOptions: {
        supportBigNumbers: true
    },
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
});

let synced = false;
const getSequelize = () => {
    if (!synced) {
        db.sync({ alter: true })
          .then(() => {
              console.log(`Database & tables synchronised!`)
          });

        synced = true;
    }

    return db;
}

export default getSequelize();
```

These are the plugins that are included in the configuration file

```
plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
  - serverless-prune-plugin
  - serverless-sequelize-migrations
```

Comment: `migrations` and `offline` are different plugins with different commands, the error you're seeing is correct. What precisely are you trying to do? If your migrations are failing, you should look at the migration code and the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple,

When importing plugins in `serverless.yml` file it is very important to import all plugins before the main plugin.

In this case, `serverless-sequelize-migrations` was imported after `serverless-offline`

So working solution is:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-sequelize-migrations
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
  - serverless-prune-plugin
```

And this migrations are executed with next command

```
serverless migrations up
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you misspelled `migrations`?

The error message says:

```
"migratins" is not a valid sub command. Run "serverless offline" to see a more helpful error message for this command.
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. In this case, it is misspelled. But the error is the same for correct command. I did update the question now.